# How to prove that $\sin^4(x)$ is even

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Function is even when $f(x) = f(-x)$, so my aim is to prove that $\sin^4(x)$ is even. So I could write it like $\sin^4(-x)$ which, in turn, is $(-\sin(x)) \times (-\sin(x)) \times( -\sin(x))\times( -\sin(x))$ and equal to the one with positive $x$. Is that enough prove or I should expose it in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

note that we have $$f(x)=(\sin(x))^4$$ then we get
$$f(-x)=(\sin(-x))^4=(-\sin(x))^4=(\sin(x))^4=f(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a good way to do it. We know that $\sin(x)$ is odd, meaning that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$. In a more condensed form:
$$\sin^4(-x)=\left(\sin(-x)\right)^4=\left(-\sin(x)\right)^4=(-1)^4\left(\sin(x)\right)^4$$
then we know $(-1)^4=1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct.

You can use the same proof to show more generally that if $f(x)$ is either even or odd, then $f(x)^{2n}$ is even for all integral $n$ (this includes negative $n$, with the caveat that the domain may need to be restricted to exclude $x$ for which $f(x)=0$).